# Installing vue cli issue

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, vue.js

What does that mean, what do I need to do with this thing. Is it a problem or a normal thing when installing vue?

```js
> nodemon@1.17.5 postinstall C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @vue/cli@3.0.0-rc.3
added 612 packages in 136.015s
```

Comment: They are just warning as it was optional and not required on your platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NPM points out:

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY

It's an optional dependency. I won't cause you any trouble while developing.